NL-NETWORK-01- java.nio.channels.AsynchronousCloseException in Neoload
A HTTP Post request was able to retrieve 200 OK response from Postman when Auth Proxy is enabled and username password is provided in settings.
The same request from NeoLoad controller is throwing “Error Code: NL-NETWORK-01
Message: Network error: An IO error occurred sending the request.
Details: java.nio.channels.AsynchronousCloseException ”.
We have enabled Authenticate to Proxy and Login Password details are provided in Proxy configuration. Also tried selecting the application proxy and load generator proxy in  Load Generators (local host) settings and still getting same error. Tried unchecking HTTP/2 in userpath validation and in population, but no luck.
Both postman and  Neoload are in the same machine. 
How to fix this issue.
